# WebView.addJavascriptInterface should not be called

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

AndroidStudio began to show me warning "WebView.addJavascriptInterface should not be called". But this method exists and is not deprecated. What's wrong with it? May be I am missing something and now there is better way to make interaction with Javascript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has known security vulnerabilities in earlier Android versions. From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29):

> This is a powerful feature, but also presents a security risk for
>   applications targeted to API level JELLY_BEAN or below, because
>   JavaScript could use reflection to access an injected object's public
>   fields. Use of this method in a WebView containing untrusted content
>   could allow an attacker to manipulate the host application in
>   unintended ways, executing Java code with the permissions of the host
>   application. Use extreme care when using this method in a WebView
>   which could contain untrusted content.